# Converter Data, hora e minuto em "time"

Tags: php

Eu preciso converter data, hora e minuto para aquela função `time()`, tendei algo como `time('$row[postdate] $row[posthora]')` não consegui, tem algum jeito de fazer isto?

Não tenho código pra postar, tenho que só converter `$row['postdate'] e $row['posthora']; // 09/03/2018 11:39`em time.

Comment: Carlos, para obter uma resposta adequada é necessário que pelo menos publique algum código que usou para converter. De outra forma, seria necessário que os colaboradores escrevessem o código na íntegra, e não é assim que funciona o Stackoverflow. Tome como base a idéia apresentada pelo Renan e tente elaborar sua própria tentativa, afinal não se sabe nada sobre os campos postdate e posthora, seus conteúdos e formatos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[A função time não recebe parâmetros e indica a quantidade de segundos desde a data base (1/1/1970).](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.time.php)

Talvez você esteja interessado em [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/datetime.construct.php). Essa função permite construir um objeto de data. Por exemplo:

```
$umDiaQualquer = new DateTime('2018-03-09 11:39');
```